# RxJS's share operator behaves differently when complete?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm struggling with something which I can't understand why it is happening .

Looking at this example :

```
 const source = Rx.Observable.of(1).share();

 source.subscribe(console.log); //1
 source.subscribe(console.log); //1
```

This prints "1" twice.  AFAIK `share` looks at `refCount`. But if we look at it - `refcount` should be ZERO here :

```
const source = Rx.Observable.of(1).share();

 source.subscribe(console.log); 
             ^--  1)refCount=1
                  2)value emitted - closing subscription ( complete)
                  3)refCount=0

 source.subscribe(console.log);
            ^-- does refCount is 1 again or  is it Zero ?
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsbin.com/pupadofone/1/edit?js,console)

Also - Things get more complicated  when the observer is *not completed*

```
const source = Rx.Observable.create((o)=>o.next(1)).share();

 source.subscribe(console.log); //1
 source.subscribe(console.log); //nothing
```

^This only yield one value

[**Demo2**](http://jsbin.com/qobilawehe/1/edit?js,console)

**Question**

Is my refCount observation was correct and why there are different results between the two examples ?

Comment: good question. I believe the share operator in rxjs v5 reconnects after completion. That might explain what you see in Demo1. Demo2 is pretty much what it has always been in all versions of rxjs. To understand properly what is happening, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141722/how-does-the-rxjs-5-share-operator-work, and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators/34669444#34669444

Comment: In short, in Demo2, when you subscribe, your `1` value is emitted **synchronously** and received by the first subscriber. When the second subscriber subscribes, well, that `1` value is already gone. If you would emit that `1` value asyncronously, both subscribers would see that value.

Comment: @user3743222 OK , so say I have a (closed) library which emits values synchronously. Is there any rxjs operator which I can chain to the results to make it  asynchrounsly ? something like `myStream$.map(f=>makeASync(f))` ?

Comment: in rxjs v4, you could do `myStream$.observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.async)` for instance. There are schedulers too in v5, but I am not cogniescent on what are the operators to use them, but I guess there should be some equivalent way to do that too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145890/what-is-a-scheduler-in-rxjs) for an explanation on schedulers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `refCount` observation is correct.

On a shared Observable, if (and only if) the `refCount` resets to `0`, then any new subscription would recreate the source Observable.

Demo 1: `refCount` resets after each subscription

Demo 2: the `refCount` would never reset since the subscriptions won't complete.

A third example:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.create((o)=>o.next(1)).share();

source.take(1).subscribe(console.log); //1
source.take(1).subscribe(console.log); //1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.8/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: So how can other consumers get the shared data in demo2? That's the idea, to share data no ? Idont see any reason why observalbe emit data, refcount>0 and the other subscriber wont get the data

Comment: The terminology here is not "shared data" but "shared observable". The idea of shared Observable is to make sure up to one Observable is created simultaneously. If you want to get all the previously emitted data on subscribing, check the replay operators.

Comment: If so , what is happening here with refcount pov ?http://jsbin.com/venabadugu/1/edit?js,console  - result is two values.

Comment: The source observable is not immediately completed, so the second subscribe shares the same Observable. The refcount is 2 after the second subscribe

Comment: Zahi I believe this should be added : _On a shared Observable, if (and only if) the refCount resets to 0, **and source is completed** then any new subscription would recreate the source Observable._